# yo @microsoft/sharepoint will retrun this error "TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function"

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, command-line, yo

I have node.js version

```
C:\helloworld-webpart>node -v
v10.24.1
```

and when i run this command using cmd windows i got this error:-

```
C:\helloworld-webpart>yo @microsoft/sharepoint
C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\resolver.js:70
    filePatterns: lookups.flatMap(prefix => [`${prefix}/*/index.ts`, `${prefix}/*/index.js`, `${prefix}/*/index.cjs`, `${prefix}/*/index.mjs`]),
                          ^

TypeError: lookups.flatMap is not a function
    at Environment.resolver.lookup (C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\resolver.js:70:27)
    at init (C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js:130:7)
    at pre (C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js:89:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mohan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js:219:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
```

any advice?